# Configure tty to prompt password for specific user

Tags: ubuntu, tty

If I switch to a tty, say tty3, it asks me for a username and then for the corresponding password.

How can I achieve, that (only on tty3) it asks me just for a password for a pre-defined user name (say `myuser`) and mentions the username, for example `password for myuser`? So I don't need to type the username but just the password on that tty.

I am using ubuntu 18.04 which uses systemd.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to add which distribution you are using, because different distributions probably run `getty` in different ways.

For `sysvinit`, it is programmed in `/etc/inittab`, where you may find a line like the following:

```
3:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty3
```

You would change that line into something like the following:

```
3:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -n -o ferdinand 38400 tty3
```

So as to cause `getty` to run `/bin/login -- ferdinand`, i.e., to prime it with the user name "ferdinand".

As documented on `man getty`, the `-n` option tells it to not prompt for username, and the `-o ferdinand` option tells it to add "ferdinand" to its login sub command line.

I would think the options work the same in other distributions, but the way of starting `getty` for `tty3` may well be different and in particular not be using `/etc/inittab`.

Answer (score 1):

The systemd equivalent to the answer by Ralph Rönnquist is to type

```
sudo EDITOR=/usr/bin/vi systemctl edit getty@tty3
```

(or your favourite editor). This gives you a temporary file in which you enter the lines:

```
 [Service]
 ExecStart=
 ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -n -o ferdinand %I
```

and exit the editor. It will create the file `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty3.service.d/override.conf`. Note, you need the first `ExecStart=` line to reset the list of commands to execute back to empty.  You can then enable and start the Unit as usual:

```
sudo systemctl enable getty@tty3
sudo systemctl start getty@tty3
```

The first creates a link in `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/` for the future. See [archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/getty#Automatic_login_to_virtual_console).